# Why in python -11%5 evaluate to 4?

Tags: python, modulus

I am familiar with the usual mod result but not for negative numbers. What is the logic?

Comment: Think about a clock with 5 hours instead of 12. With the hand at 5 (at the top position), move back 11 hours. Where's the hand? Note, you make two full rotations, and then you have a spare hour...

Answer (score 3):

Taken from https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html

> The % (modulo) operator yields the remainder from the division of the first argument by the second. The numeric arguments are first converted to a common type. A zero right argument raises the ZeroDivisionError exception. The arguments may be floating point numbers, e.g., 3.14%0.7 equals 0.34 (since 3.14 equals 4*0.7 + 0.34.) The modulo operator always yields a result with the same sign as its second operand (or zero); the absolute value of the result is strictly smaller than the absolute value of the second operand [1].

Looks like modulus operator always yields results with same sign as second operator.
Hence for -11 mod 5 will yield positive (4) result.

```
>>> -11 % 5
4
```

While 11 mod -5 will yield negative (-4) result.

```
>>> 11 % -5
-4
```

Answer (score 1):

To find `−b mod N`, just keep adding `N` to `−b` until the number is between `0` and `N`

In your case, `N = 5, b = −11`. Add `5` to `-11`, you get `-6`, again you get `-1`, and again you get `4`.

So, `−11 mod 5 = 4`.

Answer (score 0):

Python's modulo operator (%) always return a number having the same sign as the denominator (divisor)

In `-11%5` as 5 is a positive number, the output you got is positive